# Redirect to home page

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to "redirect" users from a subpage ie. index.htm#sub-page to index.htm#home with the mobileinit function?

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("/index.htm#home");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And why not

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    document.location.href="whereever";
});
```

or just

```
<script>
document.location.href="whereever";
</script>
```

or even with a metatag?

Comment: Server side redirection with HTTP302 would be much better - currently the whole page loads and 100KB of jquery stuff is loaded. Think about it

Answer (score 3):

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page_two');
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use redirect, the non-ajax web page must reload more than 100KB of JQuery JS....
I still don't want to, but in some cases it must be done by page reload (to handle the PHP Session carefully).